# Magento2 : Something went wrong while saving the rule data. Please review the error log

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

I have **Magento2 version 2.1.8**, when I tried to create new cart price rules after entering all info it doesn't get saved and shows error.

> "Something went wrong while saving the rule data. Please review the
>   error log."

Kindly guide me I am beginner in **Mangeto**.

Thanks

Comment: You need to first get the error from the /var/log/exception.log file and post it so we can see what is happening.

Comment: Post your save >> execute() and die before save()

Answer (score 0):

A good trick is to search the GitHub repository for Magento 2 for the error strings which will lead you to the classes - this error string appears in two classes.  One related to catalog rules and another related to quote - which I would guess would be what we're looking for).

The error is being generated by a catch all Exception block inside this class:

magento2/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/Controller/Adminhtml/Promo/Quote/Save.php

(or /vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Controller/Adminhtml/Promo/Quote/Save.php)

Line ~102 depending on version:

```
       } catch (\Exception $e) {

            $this->messageManager->addError(

                __('Something went wrong while saving the rule data. Please review the error log.')

            );
```

I know it's forbidden to play with core, but sometimes these things get a bit annoying - and the update should be temporary only for debugging purposes, unless you need to provide a proper error message to an external system, in which case you'd probably override the method.  **if you're not on a production server** you could try to back up the above file, then add an $e->getMessage() to the error output so you can immediately know why this is failing.

(Since you're a beginner - I would suggest checking the log file and reporting back to us instead of doing this)

```
} catch (\Exception $e) {

    $this->messageManager->addError(

                __('Something went wrong while saving the rule data. Please review the error log. ERROR: %1', $e->getMessage())

);
```

Comment: guys it was permission issue which were causing this error. Thanks for your support